# Main purpose of a Precompiled header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

My dll project is generating, not only DLL and LIB files but, also a Precompiled file header file. What is the main purpose of a PFH file in my project? Can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get rid of it, but it makes compilation notably faster by allowing the compiler to not recompile a ton (there's really a lot of code in there) of Windows SDK headers. [MSDN has more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a way of speeding up compilation, by creating a single file containing all declarations and definitions from multiple header files. Often this file is in a post-parsed format, so the compiler don't have to parse it again.